# ERROR in PYTHON type object 'Sheet' has no attribute 'add'

Tags: pandas, xlsx

I have error in python code. I am trying split workbook to different sheets based on column value, below is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from xlwings import Book, Range, Sheet
path = ('C:\Dell')
worksheet = ('FILE.xlsx')
sheet =('Temporary_Table')
 column = ('SERIAL_NUMBER')
 workbook = os.path.join(path, worksheet)
 wb = Book(workbook)
 data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet, index_col=None, na_values=[0]))
 data.sort_values(column, axis = 0, inplace = True)
 data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet, index_col=None, na_values=[0]))
data.sort_values(column, axis = 0, inplace = True)
split = data.groupby(column)
for i in split.groups:
    Sheet.add()
    Range('A1', index = False).value = split.get_group(i)
```

it keeps giving me

```
type object 'Sheet' has no attribute 'add'
```